# Access repository functions in Symfony 3

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I implement a function in a PieceRepository but I couldn't use it. I get this error when I use it in the controller:

> Undefined method 'FindAllDetailsPieces'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!

This is my `ProductRepository` file :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
class PieceRepository  extends EntityRepository  
{
    public function FindAllDetailsPieces($reference)
    {
        $query = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getManager()
        ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p, c FROM AppBundle:Piece p
        JOIN p.Media m
        JOIN p.Caracteristique c
        JOIN p.Fabricant f
        WHERE p.idPiece = :reference' 

        )->setParameter('reference', $reference);

        try {
           return $query->getResult();
         } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
          return null;
         }
    }
}
```

This where I use the method :

```
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $piece = new Piece(); //Ligne modifier
       $formRef   = $this->createForm(ReferenceType::class, $piece);

       $formRef->handleRequest($request);
       if ($formRef->isSubmitted() && $formRef->isValid()) {
           $data = $formRef->get('reference')->getData();
           var_dump($data);
           $repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Piece');
           $RechPieces = $repository->FindAllDetailsPieces($data);
           var_dump($RechPieces);
           return $this->render('default/result_ref_search.html.twig', array(
           'RechPieces' => $RechPieces
           ));
          // return $this->redirectToRoute('result_ref_search');
    }
```

I add annotaion in the entity classe

```
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\PieceRepository")
```

Comment: Show code how you use in controller

Comment: Did you added annotation in Entity?

Comment: You have to set the repository class in the entity!

Comment: you mention `ProductRepository` in your question but in code you've pasted class name is `PieceRepository`

Comment: Yes , I addes annotation in Entity

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the repository class in the entity

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PieceRepository")
 */
```

Then in you controller:

```
$em->getRespository(YourEntity::class)->FindAllDetailsPieces($reference);
```

Also delete the metadata cache if still not working (ca:cl command in Symfony, or delete the whole cache dir...)

[symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/repository.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer , But I don't know How and why I should delete the metadata cache ?

Answer (score 0):

You may have forgotten to add mapping to the `Product` entity

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * Product
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="product")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
     */
    class Product
    {
    }
```